# authentication failed due to: self signed certificate in certificate chain error after hitting localhost:3000

Tags: azure-active-directory

I tried giving - npm config set strict-ssl=false

But still I see this error, I have configured my azure environment correctly

tried skipping the tls

Comment: #azure-active-directory

Comment: Clear the npm cache: You can try clearing the npm cache using the following command: `npm cache clean --force`

Update npm: Make sure you have the latest version of npm installed by running npm `install npm@latest -g`

Comment: nothing worked, but what worked for me is process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0 in index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to index.js or app.js and add this line for least option and I hope it will work

```
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0
```